# Cell Fracture — get rid of margins between elements

Tags: cell-fracture

Even when setting Margin to 0 in the cell fracture settings, I get a visible gap between the fractured elements. Is there a way to get rid of these? I want to animate my elements breaking off one by one, so I need to use the fractured object and can not simply switch from solid to fractured at a specific keyframe, like most tutorials show.

Comment: This is an excellent question .. it's a great add-on - I can't think why this isn't implemented, unless it is, and I can't work it out.. the docs are not very complete. The 'Interior' vertex group does not include interior split-edges on the surface, which would have been a clean way through to data transfer...:(

Comment: I think I may have described my issue wrong/ in unclear terms. I’m not looking for how to animate the shards falling of one by one, I’m talking about hiding the visible gaps between shards while the object is still intact. It is basically the same issue described (and unanswered properly) here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/36094/131384

Comment: Yes, pretty much! How can I achieve this? It says Mask in the file name, does this use the Mask modifier?

Comment: No, masking wasn't used.  Thanks to your question it prompted me to 'stumble' across a way to make the segments lazy. (Not want to fall apart until a collision)  I'll post and answer for you to explain how it can be done but can I ask what your level of experience is for Blender?

Comment: I would say beginner level ;-) I do know about using constraints, if that’s what you’re doing. But that doesn’t solve my issue of being able to see cracks between the shards from the start. They are very thin, but they are visible (especially in my mesh which is more complex than a simple box). I’m not sure if those thin cracks simply didn’t show up in you gif?

Comment: If the cracks are the only issue, I'm not aware of any way of removing them.  My choice is simply to conceal them by using a wrapper such as a duplicate of the model, purged of physics etc, or a shrink-wrap for more complex topology.
If the model's geometry is complex and varied, you might try wrapping sections of it separately.  Check the demos I've left you and you won't see any cracks until the collision or close to it.  They've all been wrapped in a duplicate which is usually switched to invisible at the collision.

Comment: Yes, I know about that technique. But that doesn’t work for me because I need to be able to animate individual shards before actual physics. Anyways, I guess there’s just no way around it and I’ll have to accept the cracks. Thanks for your help anyways!

Comment: Not a problem.  Good luck with this. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to Scale Up your object, there are gaps between the cracks because the object that you want to fracture is way too small.

Answer (score 0):

I am gonna say... Because I am having the same problem... That if you are following a tutorial like: https://evermotion.org/tutorials/show/9267/create-stone-wall-in-blender-tip-of-the-week

Then leave your modifiers in the stack (don't apply them) and Shift-slide your strength and midlevel on the displacement modifier until it looks right. That is seeming to get rid of the gaps for me.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.